# Why is this OCaml code receiving "Unexpected token"?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec move_robot (pos: int) (dir: string) (num_moves: int) : int =

    let new_forward_position = pos + num_moves in
    if (new_forward_position > 99) then failwith "cannot move beyond 99 steps"
    else new_forward_position

    let new_backward_position = pos - num_moves in
    if (new_backward_position pos < 0) then failwith "cannot move less than 0 steps"
    else new_backward_position

    begin match dir with 
    | "forward" -> new_forward position
    | "backward" -> new_backward_position
    end
```

I keep on getting "unexpected token in" for the let new_backward_position line. What is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code that compiles:

```
let rec move_robot pos dir num_moves =
    let new_forward_position = pos + num_moves in
    if new_forward_position > 99 then failwith "cannot move beyond 99 steps";

    let new_backward_position = pos - num_moves in
    if new_backward_position < 0 then failwith "cannot move less than 0 steps";

    begin match dir with
    | "forward" -> new_forward_position
    | "backward" -> new_backward_position
    end
```

I modified several things:

- Important: `if foo then bar else qux` is an expression in OCaml, which takes either the value `bar` or `qux`. Thus  `bar` and `qux` needs to have the same type.
- `new_backward_position` instead of `new_backward_position pos`
- you don't need type annotations : OCaml has type inference
- no need for parentheses around the if clause
- typo in `new_forward position`

Also, with your code's logic, `let _ = move_robot 0 "forward" 5` fails. Shouldn't it return 5 instead? I suggest you define a sum type for `pos` and do a pattern matching on it first.

Comment: What typo had I made in new_forward_position?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has this basic structure if you assume the failures won't happen:

```
let f () =
    let p = 3 in p
    let q = 5 in q
    ...
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but this isn't well formed OCaml (as the compiler tells you). Maybe want you want is something more like this:

```
let f () =
    let p = 3 in
    let q = 5 in
    match ...
```

If so, you need to move your `if`s before your `in`s:

```
let f () =
    let p = if badp then failwith "" else 3 in
    let q = if badq then failwith "" else 5 in
    match ...
```

Or maybe this is more what you want:

```
let f () =
    let p = 3 in
    let () = if badp p then failwith "" in
    let q = 5 in
    let () = if badq q then failwith "" in
    match ...
```

(I hope this is helpful.)